# SSH remote command results not displaying properly

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm running the following command which works great on our Linux servers:

```
ssh -n user@192.168.1.1 "echo start; hostname;" > results.tmp
```

However, I've been trying to run the similar command on a box that is Unix based (I believe) and SSH is enabled.

So, SSH'ing into this server and running a command works:

```
 ssh admin@192.168.2.2

 SHOW NFS STATUS
```

Results:

```
 NFS Server:  Status:     Last Error:     IP Address:      Mount Path:
  Primary     active      NONE
```

Now, I try to run the command like this (to dump into a text file to parse):

```
 ssh -n admin@192.168.2.2 "SHOW NFS STATUS" > results.tmp
```

...I enter the password, and get this message, without any results:

```
 Received disconnect from 192.168.2.2: 11: Logged out.
```

I've tried removing/adding the "-n" and parentheses, and semi-colon, and just can't get it to function like the other Linux servers. 
Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks

One more thought, when I run this command:

```
 ssh -n admin@192.168.2.2 -p 22
```

I get these results:

```
 Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Comment: The `-n` option disables input from stdin, yet, the way you're running the command, you'll have to enter your password via stdin. The manual clearly says that this won't work.

Comment: I've tried adding the -n and -t option, along with -t -t. I've been playing with SSHpass because I cannot use keys as with my Linux servers in the beginning example. 

This is what I've got so far. It works as long as I don't run the command at the end :/ `sshpass -p "password" ssh -n admin@192.168.2.2 "SHOW NFS STATUS" > test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using an expect script. Thanks to everyone who helped.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 expect -c "
 spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@192.168.2.2
 #Password prompt
 expect -exact \"password:\"
 #Send password
 send \"s3cr3tp@ssword\r\"
 sleep 1
 expect -exact \"> \"
 send \"SHOW NFS SHELF 1 SLOT 1 STATUS\r\"
 #drop us back to a prompt
 expect -exact \"> \"
 #Exit
 \"exit\"
 "
```